# Hibernate menu not visible when other users logged in

Tags: hibernate

I'm aware hibernate is disabled by default in 14.04. I have enabled it by following instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html.

But I have noticed that when there are multiple logged in users, only the first user will see hibernate menu. All these users can see the hibernate menu when they are the only user in the system though.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Add `org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions` to the Action. Thus:

```
...
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
...
```